# AutoComplete показывает результат 2 раза

Tags: jquery-ui

Использую AutoComplete из JQuery UI

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Введите аккаунт пользователя</h4>

        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="search" required class="form-control" name="request" id="request" />
            <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
@Html.ActionLink("Назад","Services","Home")

<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
        $('#request').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete")', minLength: 3, messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function () { }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

получаю странный эффект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать надпись в левом нижнем углу? Дублирует выделенную опцию

Comment: Без примера кода не обойтись

Comment: @P.Ilyin кода скрипта?

Comment: да да да да да да

Comment: @P.Ilyin исправил вопрос

Comment: и разметку страницы самой

Comment: это вся разметка страницы? и весь код autocomplete?

Comment: @Grundy Это функция из библиотеки jquery UI. Мой код весь в вопросе. Есть еще мастер-страница, но она тут роли не играет.

Comment: _Есть еще мастер-страница, но она тут роли не играет._ - судя по тому, что картинка не соответствует предоставленной разметке - вполне может влиять

Comment: судя по [примеру](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOyaVn) - код абсолютно рабочий - и проблема не в коде, который приведен в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy не понимаю, чем тут поможет файл _Layout.cshtml, он довольно большой. Версии библиотек у меня старее, остальное такое же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42525/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле довольно странно поведение плагина.
Суть проблемы в том, что плагин добавляет элемент `span` с `role="status"`, в котором отображает текущий статус, например - загрузка элементов, выбранные элемент.

Данный элемент имеет класс `ui-helper-hidden-accessible` - для которого в файле стилей `jquery-ui.css` прописаны следующие свойства:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Поэтому, если данный стиль не подключен - будет показано сообщение видимое на данный момент в этом элементе.

Кстати говоря - элементы добавленные в статус никуда не деваются и просто скрываются с `display:none`, Таки образом при длительном использовании можно обнаружить гору разметки со статусами.

Судя по исходникам, отключить этот элемент никак нельзя. Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону других плагинов реализующих `autocomplete`, например в том же *bootstrap*.